# Inserir uma senha no Projeto do VBA via módulo ou SendKeys

Tags: vba, senhas

Olá, tenho uma planilha matriz que irá entrar em outras milhares de planilhas menores, ira salvar em outra extensão, colocará um código dentro desta e queria que ela bloqueasse o projeto vba dessas planilhas menores, estou tentando usar SendKeys pra isso, mas esta ineficiente.

```
Sub entrando_no_padrão()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim fld As Object
Dim fld2 As Object
Dim fld3 As Object
Dim fld4 As Object
Dim fld5 As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso3 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso4 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso5 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim ver_num As Integer
ver_num = 0

    Set fld = fso.GetFolder("C:\1")

    n = 1

    y = 1

    For Each fld In fld.SubFolders

        If fld <> "ESSE_NOME_NÃO_ENTRA" Then

            Set fld2 = fso2.GetFolder("C:\1\" & fld.Name)

            For Each fld2 In fld2.SubFolders

                If Len(Dir("C:\1\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\PCP- Planos de controle", vbDirectory) & "") > 0 Then

                    Set fld3 = fso3.GetFolder("C:\1\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\PCP- Planos de controle")

                    For Each fld3 In fld3.Files

                        Call PADRONIZAR(fld.Name, fld2.Name, fld3.Name)

                        SendKeys "%f" & "p" & "^{TAB}" & "{+}" & "{TAB}" & "34670920" & "{TAB}" & "34670920" & "{TAB}" & "~" & "%{F4}"

                    Next fld3

                End If

                If Len(Dir("C:\1\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\PEP - Plano de embalagem", vbDirectory) & "") > 0 Then

                    Set fld4 = fso4.GetFolder("C:\1\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\PEP - Plano de embalagem")

                    For Each fld4 In fld4.Files

                        Call PADRONIZAR(fld.Name, fld2.Name, fld4.Name)

                        SendKeys "%f" & "p" & "^{TAB}" & "{+}" & "{TAB}" & "34670920" & "{TAB}" & "34670920" & "{TAB}" & "~" & "%{F4}"

                    Next fld4

                End If

                If Len(Dir("C:\1\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\FIT - Ficha de Instrução de Trabalho", vbDirectory) & "") > 0 Then

                    Set fld5 = fso5.GetFolder("C:\1\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\FIT - Ficha de Instrução de Trabalho")

                    For Each fld5 In fld5.Files

                        Call PADRONIZAR(fld.Name, fld2.Name, fld5.Name)

                        SendKeys "%f" & "p" & "^{TAB}" & "{+}" & "{TAB}" & "34670920" & "{TAB}" & "34670920" & "{TAB}" & "~" & "%{F4}"

                    Next fld5

                End If

            Next fld2

        End If

    Next fld

    If x <> x Then

final:

        Open "\\caminha\para\abrir\um\txt" For Append As #2

            Print #2, fld2.Path

        Close #2

    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

É isso, por enquanto.

Comment: Eu respondi a sua pergunta mas fiquei em dúvida se você quer bloquear a visualização do VBA na planilha geradora ou nas geradas por ela.

Comment: As geradas pela matriz

Comment: Via `VBA` você não consegue definir um código para proteger o "`VBA`" das planilhas menores pois o `VBAProject` não expõe a senha para ser definida via código, isso teria que ser feito via **SendKeys**

Comment: Não vi nenhum código gerando planilhas nesse trecho que você postou. Seria esse `PADRONIZAR`?

Comment: "Gerar" é um termo meio ambíguo, ele entra em uma planilha salva ela com outra extensão, insere um código e quero que bloqueie o projeto.

Comment: Na verdade não, pois isso seria alterar, gerar seria criar do zero. De qualquer maneira o termo não é o que está em discussão e nem foi a palavra que você usou realmente. O que quero dizer é que não consigo entender onde está abrindo a outra panilha, inserindo código e alterando a extensão.

Comment: Muito cuidado com a maneira que está sendo feito essa alteração para outra extensão pois o arquivo pode se tornar inválido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você entrar no editor do VBA, e na árvore do projeto, definir uma senha para o mesmo.

Segue o passo a passo (feito no Word porém serve para todo o Office):

**Passo 1**

[image: Propriedades]

**Passo 2**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Edição 1:**

Segundo o seu comentário recente, você gostaria de bloquear o código VBA das planilhas geradas por essa inicial.
Acontece que isso não é possível de uma maneira usual, pois o `VBAProject` não expõe a senha para ser definida via código.

Entretanto existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso, como por exemplo utilizando **SendKeys** *(não recomendado)*:

```
Sub AddNewPlan()
    Dim NewPlan As Workbook
    Set NewPlan = Workbooks.Add

    With NewPlan
        .Title = "New Plan"

        Call AddSampleCode(NewPlan)
        Call ProtectVBProject(NewPlan, "abc123")

        .SaveAs "C:\NewPlan.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        .Close
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ProtectVBProject(WB As Workbook, ByVal Password As String)
    ' Ativa a planilha a ser bloqueada
    WB.Activate

    ' Envia o comando para abrir o VBA
    SendKeys "%{F11}", True

    ' Abre a janela de proteção do projeto VBA
    WB.VBProject.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute

    ' Envia os comandos para digitar a senha e confirmar
    SendKeys "+{TAB}{RIGHT}%V{+}{TAB} {TAB}" & Password & "{TAB}" & Password & "~", True
End Sub

Private Sub AddSampleCode(WB As Workbook)
    Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim xLine As Long

    With WB
        Set xPro = .VBProject
        Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
        xCom.Name = "ModTeste" ' Adiciona um novo módulo padrão a planilha
        Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

        'Adiciona o código do novo modulo
        With xMod
            .InsertLines 2, "Sub Teste()"
            .InsertLines 3, "Msgbox ""teste"""
            .InsertLines 4, "End Sub"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Esse método foi discutido nesse tópico: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=13006&p=65776#post65776

Entretanto não consegui fazer com que funcionasse corretamente para mim, então eu o modifiquei um pouco pois percebi que é necessário que haja ao menos um módulo padrão para que o bloqueio do VBA ocorra, então incluí a criação de um módulo de teste no exemplo. **É necessário a inclusão da referência Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3**

As outras maneiras seriam criar um modelo de planilha com o código VBA definido e preencher essa planilha com dados ou via Windows API *(que seria mais complexo e não possuo nenhum exemplo agora)*.

De qualquer maneira, se o usuário realmente quiser ver o código `VBA` existem maneiras de se conseguir, mesmo com senha, por exemplo utilizando o OpenOffice para abrir o seu arquivo.

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo usar, eu devo ativar alguma Referência?

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de mencionar, é necessário referenciar `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3`. Eu editei a minha resposta com o código alterado, veja se funciona pra você.

Comment: Houve um problema, eu testei o SendKeys, deu tudo certo, mas ele não está escrevendo na outra planilha, e acaba ativando a minha planilha matriz em vez da que foi gerada.

Comment: Sem ter conhecimento do código que você está utilizando não consigo imaginar o que pode ser. Edite a sua postagem com o código que está utilizando, **evitando** exibir senhas ou dados pessoais.

Comment: Não postei tudo do código, porque ele é muito extenso, mas essa é a parte em que tentei colocar.

Comment: Para ativar a planilha correta você deve passar o objeto `Workbook` correto para o primeiro parâmetro da função `ProtectVBProject`.

Comment: Então eu consegui aplicar seu código, muito obrigado, gostaria de perguntar como conseguiu o código do `CommandBars` porque eu preciso do que chama a senha do projeto, pra eu poder bloquear e desbloquear o projeto rapidamente.

Comment: O código eu consegui do link de exemplo que postei, não cheguei a procurar. Sei que é possível, mas isso seria uma outra pergunta, não é bacana pra comunidade e nem legível ter respostas de outras dúvidas em comentários.

Comment: Tudo bem, farei outra pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tenho um sistema que usa as planilhas como base de dados, e quando quero acessar a base, tenho que digitar uma senha, se te ajudar o código é esse:

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click()
If txtSenha.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Digite a senha para acessar o Arquivo", vbCritical
ElseIf txtSenha <> "vba" Then   'senha
    MsgBox "Digite a senha corretamente para acessar o Arquivo", vbCritical
Else
    Application.Visible = True
    Unload Me
    UserForm6.Hide  'aqui é a tela principal do meu sistema fica invisivel
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Só criar um UserForm com um TextBox e um Botão.